What is the oldest instance of a Christian theologian saying that an issue is OK to disagree about?
There's an infamous story from early church history of the dispute over the correct date for celebration of Easter, which got so heated that people even called their opponents heretics over it and attempted to excommunicate them. (See Eusebius, Ecclesial History Book V.23-25).
On the other hand, the earliest writing I know of to acknowledge faithfulness of Christians on both sides of a debate is the issue of the future millennial kingdom: Justin Martyr says this in approximately 160 AD in his Dialogue with Trypho ch.80, where he says that "many good and pious" Christians think otherwise. Is this the oldest example of a Christian author acknowledging legitimate disagreement about some issue? If not, what is the older "acceptable" dispute?
(And let's leave out the issues mentioned by Paul in Romans 14 - I'd like to know about sources outside of the Bible itself.)

Yeah, those days anathema is a word that was used a lot, even for non-Biblical concern like the veneration of icons, which (to my displeasure) was quite violent.  Part of Gavin Ortlund's latest video on Icon veneration as accretion provides the historical understanding of anathema which is a lot stronger than Catholics & Eastern Orthodox churches today.

I take it gendered hair length per I Cor. 11:16 also doesn't count. :)

Yes that also doesn't count. And I don't even see where in that passage Paul says it's something OK to disagree about. Most Christians today would say that it is but that's an inference from Paul's reasoning and not what he said expressly.
